# Does Android compress raw XML resources?

Tags: android

Does Android compress raw XML resources i.e. those under `res/xml` directory?

I have some resources in the `assets` and planning to move them to `res/xml` (so I can localize them) but I'm not sure if they will be compressed then.

I understand I can check this out by unzipping some apk but maybe someone already knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/) blog post by Brian Hardy. All "compressible files" are compressed even xml files. Xml files are compressed by aapt into a binary format. If you don't want your files to be compressed, you can save them as one of the file types in the blog post. Also, you can package your data into a .zip file (android won't try to compress it) and then unzip it yourself when reading it.

Comment: So then, when I use a Xml parser on R.xml resosurces Abdroid unzips a required resource then parses it?

Comment: No it does not unzip it. The xml files are not zipped. They are converted into a compressed binary format. The methods defined in android.content.res.Resources can parse this format. For example, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int)) method can parse a generic xml file using the id that was given by aapt at build time.